# Count total from multiple row results using SQL

Tags: sql

say I have a table like this

```
user, count
1     5
2     3
3     20
4     13
5     10
```

I want to get the total from all the `count` row, so basically `5+3+20+13+10=51`, I want to get the `51`

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `SUM()` (although your formula doesn't match the data).

Comment: more hints: try not to use reserved words as column names, and when posting a question about sql, add the relevan't rdbms tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ahh yes, thanks so much, and I fixed the formula, was a typo

Comment: @ZoharPeled Why would you advise against using reserved words as column names, if I may ask? And thanks.

Comment: @user6613235, avoiding reserved names; this makes a query look confusing, take for example `SELECT count, count(*) FROM tablename Group By count`

Comment: @christiandev OH, yea, true, thanks so much everyone.

Comment: Let's just say that they are called `reserved` for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
select sum(count) as Total from tablename;
```

Comment: @George identifiers shall be quoted with double quotes: "count".  square brackets are for [Bill Gatetifiers]

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(count) from yourtablename
```